# PHP urlencode for Jquery string

Tags: php, urlencode

I'm struggling to finish a final piece of my project - I have a textbox that is populated by a date time picker in the format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM

I need to pass this value in to a URL string, which is then sent to a database table.

As I''m using a modal to gather the additional information I need I have a Jquery script to alter my HREF tab on the submit button:

```
$(document).on('click','#myModal<?php echo $v['id']; ?> .modal-footer a', function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                //function to update HREf attribute with values from modal screen
                var uri = <?php urlencode('2016/01/01/ 21:00')?>
                //$('#divert_until_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>').text();

                window.location.href=window.location.href= $(this).attr('href') + '&to=' + $('#divert_to_<?php echo $v['id']; ?> option:selected').text() + '&type= ' + $('#divert_type_<?php echo $v['id']; ?> option:selected').text() + '&until= ' + uri;

            });
```

Currently, I receive all the information (ID, TO, and TYPE) but nothing from UNTIL. Above I am trying to save the fixed string '2016/01/01 21:00' to the database.

Here is my code to catch the URL:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='add_divert') {

if(!isset($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['notification'] = array('type'=>'bad','msg'=>$lang['ADMIN_INVALID_ID']);
    redirect(ROOT_URL.'stores.php?search='.$_REQUEST['search'].$pg.$st.$fl);
}

$db = db_connect();
if($db->update('stores',array('divert_enabled'=>1,'divert_type'=>($_GET['type']),'divert_until'=>($_GET['until']),'divert_to'=>($_GET['to'])),$_GET['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['notification'] = array('type'=>'good','msg'=>'Divert notice added to destination.');
} else {
    $_SESSION['notification'] = array('type'=>'bad','msg'=>'Could not add a divert notice to the destination.');
}
redirect(ROOT_URL.'stores.php?search='.$_REQUEST['search'].$pg.$st.$fl);
}
```

I've tried a few variations, but am just going round in circles.

Ultimately I need to retried the date time string from `('#divert_until_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>').text()`

Thanks!

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: How do I pass the date time value from the text box to the URL in a format that is accepted by the receiving query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY bad, was using `.text` instead of `.val`

final code:

```
$(document).on('click','#myModal<?php echo $v['id']; ?> .modal-footer a', function(e)
     {
     e.preventDefault();
    //function to update HREf attribute with values

    var until_str = $('#divert_until_' + <?php echo $v['id']; ?>).val();
    var uri = encodeURI(until_str);

    window.location.href=window.location.href= $(this).attr('href') + '&to=' + $('#divert_to_<?php echo $v['id']; ?> option:selected').text() + '&type= ' + $('#divert_type_<?php echo $v['id']; ?> option:selected').text() + '&until=' + uri;

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode the value using JavaScript function [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) then send this.

On your receiving php server use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) php function to obtain the original value.

Comment: Thanks, I've had some success urlencoding a fixed string, but just overlooking something now that prevents that textbox values from sending properly.

Comment: Well, it was EncodeURI and changing to .val that got it going - so, mostly right!